# How to protect a user password with bcrypt and mongoid

Tags: mongoid, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I've just started out using `MongoDB` and, in particular, `Mongoid`.

naturally I'd like to ensure my `User`'s passwords are kept nice and secure, and previously I'd have done this with `ActiveRecord` and used `bcrypt`. I'm looking for a nice, clean, secure, simple way to implement the same sort of thing using `Mongoid`.

I've taken a look at [mongoid-encryptor](https://github.com/juno/mongoid-encryptor) but I've not quite got my head around how to use it.

Assume my simplified `User` looks like this, as per the example in `mongoid-encryptor`'s Readme file.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Encryptor
  field :name
  field :password
  encrypts :password
end
```

And in my WebApp (using `Sinatra` in this case) I'd define a helper such as

```
def login (name, cleartxtpass)
  return User.where(name: name, password: cleartxtpass).first
end
```

1. How do I get it to use `bcrypt`?
2. Is there any pre-processing I need to do with `cleartxtpass` or will `Mongoid::Encryptor` just handle that?  It's not clear from the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Okay well after some digging I decided to not bother using `Mongoid::Encryptor` but to stick to the tried and tested way I used to do these things when using `ActiveRecord`.

So now my `User` looks like

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :password_hash, type: String
  index({name: 1}, {unique: true, name: 'user_name_index'})

  include BCrypt
  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

and my authenticate helper method looks like

```
  def auth_user(username, password)
    user = User.where(name: username).first
    return user if user && user.password == password
    return nil
  end
```

That works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The simply way to do it is:

```html
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  field :name, type: String
  field :password_digest, type: String

  has_secure_password
end
```